# How to wait for suspendCoroutine in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to write tests for my android application. Sometimes the viewModel executes tasks in the background using Kotlins coroutine launch function. These tasks are executed in the viewModelScope that the androidx.lifecycle library so handily provides. In order to still test these functions, I replaced the default android Dispatchers with Dispatchers.Unconfined, which runs the code synchronously.

At least in most of the cases. When using suspendCoroutine, the Dispatchers.Unconfined will not be suspended and later resumed, but instead will simply return. The documentation of `Dispatchers.Unconfined` reveals why:

> [Dispatchers.Unconfined] lets the coroutine resume in whatever thread that is used by the corresponding suspending function.

So by my understanding, the coroutine is not actually suspended, but the rest of the async function after `suspendCoroutine` is run on the thread that calls `continuation.resume`. Therefore the test fails.

Example:

```
class TestClassTest {
var testInstance = TestClass()

@Test
fun `Test with default dispatchers should fail`() {
    testInstance.runAsync()
    assertFalse(testInstance.valueToModify)
}

@Test
fun `Test with dispatchers replaced by Unconfined should pass`() {
    testInstance.DefaultDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    testInstance.IODispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    testInstance.runAsync()
    assertTrue(testInstance.valueToModify)
}

@Test
fun `I need to also test some functions that use suspend coroutine - How can I do that?`() {
    testInstance.DefaultDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    testInstance.IODispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    testInstance.runSuspendCoroutine()
    assertTrue(testInstance.valueToModify)//fails
}
}

class TestClass {
var DefaultDispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default
var IODispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(DefaultDispatcher)
var valueToModify = false

fun runAsync() {
    viewModelScope.launch(DefaultDispatcher) {
        valueToModify = withContext(IODispatcher) {
            sleep(1000)
            true
        }
    }
}

fun runSuspendCoroutine() {
    viewModelScope.launch(DefaultDispatcher) {
        valueToModify = suspendCoroutine {
            Thread {
                sleep(1000)
                //long running operation calls listener from background thread
                it.resume(true)
            }.start()
        }
    }
}
}
```

I was experimenting around with `runBlocking`, however it only helps if you call launch using the `CoroutineScope` created by `runBlocking`. But since my code is launching on the `CoroutineScope` provided by `viewModelScope` this will not work. If possible I would prefer not to inject a CoroutineScope everywhere, because any lower level class could (and does) make their own CoroutineScope as in the example, and then the Test has to know a lot about the implementation details. The idea behind the scopes is that every class has control over cancelling their asynchronous operations. The viewModelScope for example is by default cancelled when the viewModel is destroyed.

My question:
**What coroutine dispatcher could I use that runs launch and withContext etc blocking (like `Dispatchers.Unconfined`) and also runs suspendCoroutine blocking?**

Comment: It is hard to undestand the problem with the code as presented. Could you separate your testing code from your production code?
Your test method should call your production code and not have it inlined. This way it would be easier to reason about your problem

Comment: @EricMartori Is it now more understandable?

Comment: It is better now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the helps of other answers, I have found the following solution. As sedovav suggested in his answer, I can run the task async and wait for the Deferred. Basically the same idea, I can run the task with launch and wait for the job that handles the task. The problem in both cases is, how do I get the Deferred or Job.

I found a solution to this. Such a Job is always a child of the Job contained in the CoroutineContext which is part of the CoroutineScope. So the following code does solve the problem, both in my example code as well as in the actual android application.

```
@Test
fun `I need to also test some functions that use suspend coroutine - How can I do that?`() {
    replaceDispatchers()
    testInstance.runSuspendCoroutine()
    runBlocking {
        (testInstance.viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]?.children?.forEach { it.join() }
    }
    assertTrue(testInstance.valueToModify)//fails
}
```

It does seem a bit like a hack, so if someone has a reason why this is dangerous, please tell. Also it won't work if there is another underlying CoroutineScope created by some other class. But it is the best solution I have.

Comment: This doesn't work if the view model is collecting a SharedFlow for example. That's because it is a Job that doesn't finish (unless viewModelScope is cancelled or destroyed, but that's not usable in a scenario like the example above). Similar issues would occur collecting a StateFlow or a Channel.

Comment: Of course one could call join only on the relevant `Job` but identifying it is tricky and not maintainable long-term. Relying on this can cause problems later if consuming `SharedFlow` is introduced later on. So I don't recommend using this approach.

Answer (score 8):

How about passing the coroutine context to your model? Something like

```
class Model(parentContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default) {
    private val modelScope = CoroutineScope(parentContext)
    var result = false

    fun doWork() {
        modelScope.launch {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            result = true
        }
    }
}

@Test
fun test() {
    val model = runBlocking {
        val model = Model(coroutineContext)
        model.doWork()
        model
    }
    println(model.result)
}
```

**Update**
for viewModelScope from androidx.lifecycle you can just use this test rule

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutinesTestRule : TestWatcher() {
    private val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        dispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }
}
```

here are the test model and the test

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var result = false

    fun doWork() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            result = true
        }
    }
}

class MainViewModelTest {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var coroutinesRule = CoroutinesTestRule()

    private val model = MainViewModel()

    @Test
    fun `check result`() {
        model.doWork()
        assertTrue(model.result)
    }
}
```

don't forget to add `testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"` to get `TestCoroutineDispatcher`

Comment: This does work. However it will be a lot of effort to make sure that every CoroutineScope is based on a runBlocking context. I can't even make this a junit rule then, because the test needs to run inside the runBlocking, so it needs to be done in every test that calls such code... Also I wouldn't be able to use the viewModelScope provided by androidx.lifecycle. 
But this is the best answer so far, so unless something better comes, I will award it the bounty.

Comment: ah, you are using viewModelScope? There is a simple way. I'll update my answer

Comment: On first look the TestCoroutineDispatcher seems to have the same effect as Dispatchers.Unconfined. But I will need to make a more extensive test tomorrow to make sure this isn't because of my test setup.

Comment: I've read your new question explanation. Yes, you're right. The test rule won't work

Answer (score 4):

Now, you can use `runTest`

From Android developer site https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"
}
```

Test

```
suspend fun fetchData(): String {
    delay(1000L)
    return "Hello world"
}

@Test
fun dataShouldBeHelloWorld() = runTest {
    val data = fetchData()
    assertEquals("Hello world", data)
}
```

And you can use `advanceUntilIdle()` for queued coroutines

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you want everything in your production code to run in the main thread of your test. But it doesn't seem to be achievable as something may be run in a regular thread pool/background, and if have no means to synchronize/join the background process in your code you probably in trouble. The best thing is to join background threads somehow in a coroutine and `await` that coroutine in the test before the assertions. It may require you to change your existing production code.

I'm talking about a different approach to write your code. Surely, it's not always possible. I've updated your example accordingly to illustrate my point:

```
class TestClassTest {
    var testInstance = TestClass()

    @Test
    fun `Test with default dispatchers should fail`() = runBlocking {
        val valueToModify = testInstance.runAsync().await()
        assertTrue(valueToModify)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test with dispatchers replaced by Unconfined should pass`() = runBlocking {
        testInstance.DefaultDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
        testInstance.IODispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
        val valueToModify = testInstance.runAsync().await()
        assertTrue(valueToModify)
    }

    @Test
    fun `I need to also test some functions that use suspend coroutine - How can I do that?`() = runBlocking {
        testInstance.DefaultDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
        testInstance.IODispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined
        val valueToModify = testInstance.runSuspendCoroutine().await()
        assertTrue(valueToModify)//fails
    }
}

class TestClass {
    var DefaultDispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Default
    var IODispatcher: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
    val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(DefaultDispatcher)

    fun runAsync(): Deferred<Boolean> {
        return viewModelScope.async(DefaultDispatcher) {
            withContext(IODispatcher) {
                sleep(1000)
                true
            }
        }
    }

    fun runSuspendCoroutine(): Deferred<Boolean> {
        return viewModelScope.async(DefaultDispatcher) {
            suspendCoroutine<Boolean> {
                Thread {
                    sleep(1000)
                    //long running operation calls listener from background thread
                    it.resume(true)
                }.start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does sound like a reasonable idea. If I could await the work done in my viewModelScope, it would probably work. Do you have any idea how I would do that?

Comment: ah so you want to await the job that is started. That is sadly not possible. In my case I trigger the event via a LiveData that is observed, so I can't get any return values.

Comment: I have found a solution to get the job to join it. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what `runBlocking` was created to do. Simply replace the `GlobalScope.launch` call:

```
result = runBlocking {
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        Thread {
            sleep(1000)
            //long running operation calls listener from background thread
            continuation.resume(true)
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that this is not clear, the launch call is not in the test methods but in the production code. Otherwise I wouldn't need a test rule to replace the Dispatchers. The code above is simply a minimal reproducible code bit.